# SSH agent forwarding on Windows (pageant)

Tags: node.js, ssh

When I try to connect through SSH from any language (tried with Golang & Nodejs) to one of my servers from Windows the agent forwarding doesn't work.
I'm saying this because some commands like git pull are throwing errors (Permission denied (publickey)), while there aren't if I login directly using Putty. 
I tried to use the env. variable ***SSH_AUTH_SOCK*** but it seems there's no such variable set on Windows. I expected Pageant doing the job.

Code example in NodeJS ([simple-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh) lib):

```
this.ssh = new SSH({
    // other unimportant variables
    agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK, // which is undefined
    agentForward: true
});
```

How does this work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For pageant on Windows, you should use the special `'pageant'` value for `agent` instead:

```
this.ssh = new SSH({
    // other unimportant variables
    agent: 'pageant',
    agentForward: true
});
```

Comment: Mh... still get the key error.. Where did you find that?

Comment: It's from the documentation in the readme. Also, I tried this just now on a Windows machine and it worked just fine. Are you sure you have pageant loaded and your key added to it?